# Updating millions of rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb, innodb

I'm trying to update few millions of rows in MySQL InnoDB table, but getting the following error:

```
ERROR 1206 (HY000): The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size
```

As I read, the problem is in row locking and in the big number of rows. So I tried to avoid row locking by locking the table itself and splitting query by LIMIT. Also I changed the config with **innodb_buffer_pool_size=4G**. But in total that does not work and the error still appearing.

```
MariaDB [data]> LOCK TABLES contacts WRITE;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [data]> UPDATE `contacts` SET `field1` = `field2` WHERE `field1` = 0 AND `field2` > 0 LIMIT 1000000;
ERROR 1206 (HY000): The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance. Have no idea why that happens.

Comment: could your try to update it on primary_key column ?

Comment: So let me get  this right, you first lock the table for wirte access and the try to update? that makes no sense. Run a query like `SELECT * FROM ciontacts WHERE `field1` = 0 AND `field2` > 0 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1000000 FOR UPDATE;`  and then run the update, so that the rows that ypou need are locke, also a limit without order males also no sense

Comment: Thanks. But it takes a very long time to execute this SELECT query. I need to update ~100M rows in total. So I think the better way is to lock the whole table instead of spending time to lock rows individually. So the question is why rows lock is still happening if I locked the table?

Answer (score 0):

(This sounds like a duplicate.)

- Batch only 1000 at a time
- Have `INDEX(field1, field2, id)`
- Walk through the table in id order.  More discussion here: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks

That last suggestion plays a game with

```
SELECT ... WHERE id > $leftoff ORDER BY id LIMIT 1000,1
```

together with

```
UPDATE ... WHERE id > $leftoff AND id <= $newleftoff AND $filter
```

to avoid touching more than 1000 rows at a time -- first to limit which rows to consider, then to work on them.  And, since, the table is "clustered" on `PRIMARY KEY(id)`, there is very little I/O.  It will not touch any block more than twice (once to read, once to write, if necessary).  It will be efficient even for huge tables and a tiny buffer_pool.

Answer (score 0):

Consider implementing [other optimization techniques](https://www.laymansmag.com/how-to-make-mysql-database-faster/) to your queries